# HighCHarts 3.0 with data plugin

Tags: highcharts

Under the new HighCharts 3.0 - they included a data module plugin (example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AYYCv/)). The actual script is [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/modules/data.src.js)

I have a table like

```
<table id="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Business</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1/01/2013</td>
            <td>John Apple</td>
            <td>51 Blah Street, CA</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>$54.33</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can map the date, and price in the new format ? So that the price is Y and the date is X and the series is Y,X

Currently, the example only shows how to map the entire table - but I only want to map 2 columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data module is taking or whole table, or you can specify :
 * - endColumn : Integer
 * In tabular input data, the first row (indexed by 0) to use. Defaults to the last column containing data.
 *
 * - endRow : Integer
 * In tabular input data, the last row (indexed by 0) to use. Defaults to the last row containing data.

There is no option to specify only some of columns/rows.